# Program not compiling. What is the error

Tags: exception, java-7, ioexception, numberformatexception

I am trying to run the below simple code in command prompt for last few hours. Still not able to fix the error.

What is the problem here. I'm not able to find.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        try {
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            i = Integer.parseInt(din.readLine());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException || IOException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: If you plan on processing `i` after the try-catch block, you will get another error ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Need to use single `|` operator. Not `||`.

```
catch(NumberFormatException | IOException exception)
```

Comment: Gotta love Java 7 syntax candies :)